# Logarithmic integral, $π(x)$ and $x/(\ln x)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

The function $\text{Li}$ (logarithmic integral) is defined for $x>0$
by
$$
\text{Li}(x)=\int_2^{x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}.
$$
The prime number theorem, proven by Hadamard and de la Vallée-Poussin in 1896 asserts that $π(x) \sim \text{Li}(x)$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$ where
$
π(x)=\text{Card}\{2\le p\in \mathbb N, \text{ $p$ is prime}\}.
$
It was proven by J. Littlewood in 1914 that the difference $d(x)=\text{Li}(x)-π(x)$ changes sign an infinite number of times, although for $x\le 10^{25}$, $d(x)>0$. (I guess that the $10^{25}$ could be enlarged.) I think that it is also known that for $x$ quite large, say in the interval $[10^{300}, 10^{500}]$, there exists $x$ such that $d(x)<0$. Thanks to the answers below, I have understood that there is no explicit value of $x$ for which we know that $d(x)<0$.

A related question: is it true that for $x$ large enough
$$
π(x)\ge \frac{x}{\ln x}?
$$

Comment: Not yet. See the discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes'_number#More_recent_estimates

Comment: x almost=1.45136923488338...

Answer (score 7):

No explicit values are known.

For a recent reference, see *"A still sharper region where $π(x) − \text{li}(x)$ is positive"*, by Y. Saouter, T.S. Trudgian and P. Demichel (2014). An extract from the last section of the paper:

> The last point we shall address is the existence of smaller values of
>   $x$ for which $π(x)>\text{li}(x)$. The is no practical way to test an
>   isolated value of $x$. Analytical methods, such as the one described
>   here, can only give intervals of positivity.

PS. Yes, $ π(x)\ge \frac{x}{\ln x}$ for all $x\geq17$. See *"Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers"* by Rosser and Schoenfeld, page 6, for example.

Answer (score 6):

To your added question: yes, $\pi(x)\ge \frac{x}{\ln x}$ certainly holds for $x\geq 59$ by Theorem 1 in Rosser-Schoenfeld: Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just to address the question $\pi(X) \geq \frac{X}{\log X}$? The above answers are sufficient -- let's just see why that is elementarily.

Let's assume RH just to illustrate the following idea/approximation for $\pi(X)$. Thus, we have $\pi(X) = Li(X) + O(X^{\frac{1}{2} + \varepsilon})$. If we rewrite $Li(X)$ via integration by parts, we see $Li(X) = \frac{X}{\log X} + \int_2^{X} \frac{1}{\log^2 t} dt + O(1) = \frac{X}{\log X} + \frac{X}{\log^2 X} + O\left(\frac{X}{\log^3 X}\right)$. Thus, $\pi(X) - \frac{X}{\log X} \sim \frac{X}{\log^2 X}$; now just take $X$ sufficiently large!

Note: one can iteratively expand via integration by parts, and the RH assumption emphasizes no term $\frac{X}{\log^N X}$ is outraced by the error term. However, it is overkill as the classical PNT estimate is also small enough.